# How to get the loops and selection part of this program correct?

Tags: c++

heres my program, im tasked to create a calculator that can calculate either the volume or surface based on the users input. there are supposed to be 8 different geometry shapes (A-G) in which in supposed to calculate but im not able to get pass the first one.the user needs to input the code(A-G) and option to calculate either surface oor area (1 or 2) correctly if not the program will reloop .once the program finsihes calculating the program will ask the user if they want to reuse the program or exit te program. i also encounter some erros with my password. the program is supposed to quit after 3 wrong attempts but instead it quits after 4.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char code, option;
    int n, op, s, l, w, r, h;
    float pi=3.14, total = 0;
    string password, username;
    int attempts_left = 3;
    n=0;

    cout << "Enter password: ";
    getline(cin, password);

    cout << "Enter username: ";
    getline(cin, username);

    while (attempts_left > 0 && (password != "abc" || username != "abc")) {
    cout << "Invalid password or username. You have " << --attempts_left << " attempts left.\n";

    cout << "Enter password: ";
    getline(cin, password);

    cout << "Enter username: ";
    getline(cin, username);
    }

    if (attempts_left > 0) {
        cout << "Access granted.\n";




    while (code !='A' || code !='B' || code !='C' || code !='D' || code !='E' ||code !='F' || code !='G') 
    {

        cout << "Enter code (A-G): ";
        cin >> code;

        

        if (code=='A') 
        { while (option != 1 || option != 2) {
        
            cout <<"Enter value: ";
            cin >> s;
            
            if (option == 1 ) {
                total = s*s*s;
                cout << total;
            }
            
            else 
            { 
            total = 6*s*s;
            cout << total;
            }
            }
        
        }
     
    }
}
```

im expecting an output screen something like this (say i selected A with option 1 my value s being 2)

answer = 8

Would you like to continue the program? (Y/N)

`your text`

Comment: Please fix the formatting, why is there `your text` literally everywhere?

Comment: Put 3 backticks (`\``) before and after the start of your code, instead of doing whatever you did here.

Comment: I'm too grumpy to clean this one up today.

Answer (score 0):

quick scan

- `code` is not initalized before that `while`
- `code !='A' || code !='B' || code !='C' || code !='D' || code !='E' ||code !='F' || code !='G'` is always going to be true.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your main loop issues, regarding password, main options (A-G) and continue program Y/N, this should get you most of the way there:

```
int main() {
   char code, option, continueProgram;
   int n, op, s, l, w, r, h;
   float pi = 3.14, total = 0;
   string password, username;
   int attempts_left = 3;
   n = 0;

   cout << "Enter password: ";
   getline(cin, password);

   cout << "Enter username: ";
   getline(cin, username);

   attempts_left--;
   while (attempts_left > 0 && (password != "abc" || username != "abc")) {
       cout << "Invalid password or username. You have " << attempts_left << " attempts left.\n";

       cout << "Enter password: ";
       getline(cin, password);

       cout << "Enter username: ";
       getline(cin, username);

       attempts_left--;
   }

   if (attempts_left >= 1) {
       cout << "Access granted.\n";
       // Making a table
       cout << " ____________________________________________" << endl;
       cout << "|       |                                    |" << endl;
       cout << "|  CODE |           3D GEOMETRY              |" << endl;
       cout << "|_______|____________________________________|" << endl;
       cout << "|       |                                    |" << endl;
       cout << "|   A   |              CUBE                  |" << endl;
       cout << "|_______|____________________________________|" << endl;
       cout << "|       |                                    |" << endl;
       cout << "|   B   |         RECTANGLE SOLID            |" << endl;
       cout << "|_______|____________________________________|" << endl;
       cout << "|       |                                    |" << endl;
       cout << "|   C   |             SPHERE                 |" << endl;
       cout << "|_______|____________________________________|" << endl;
       cout << "|       |                                    |" << endl;
       cout << "|   D   |     RIGHT CIRCULAR CYLINDER        |" << endl;
       cout << "|_______|____________________________________|" << endl;
       cout << "|       |                                    |" << endl;
       cout << "|   E   |       RIGHT CIRCULAR CONE          |" << endl;
       cout << "|_______|____________________________________|" << endl;
       cout << "|       |                                    |" << endl;
       cout << "|   F   |         SQUARE PYRAMID             |" << endl;
       cout << "|_______|____________________________________|" << endl;
       cout << "|       |                                    |" << endl;
       cout << "|   G   |      REGULAR TETRAHEDRON           |" << endl;
       cout << "|_______|____________________________________|" << endl;

   }
   else {
       cout << "Access denied.\n";
       return 0;
   }


   cout << "Enter code (A-G): ";
   cin >> code;

   continueProgram = 'Y';
   while (continueProgram == 'Y')
   {
       while (code != 'A' && code != 'B' && code != 'C' && code != 'D' && code != 'E' && code != 'F' && code != 'G')
       {
           cout << "Invalid code\n";
           cout << "Enter code (A-G): ";
           cin >> code;
       }

       if (code == 'A')
       {
           cout << "Enter value: ";
           cin >> s;
       
           total = s * s * s;
       }
       else if (code == 'B')
       {
           // Do something
       }

       cout << "Result = " << total << '\n';

       cout << "Would you like to continue the program? (Y/N)";
       cin >> code;
   }
    
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fixes as an answer.  Show where you made changes to the OP's code to resolve the issues.  I'm not in the mood to copy your code and the OP's code into a "diff" tool to see what changes you made, and then try to figure out why you made the changes.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm still pretty new here, so please forgive me. there were various fixes/changes to the OP's code, how best should I show this? should I just add additional comments to the code?

Comment: You could either add comments to the code, or break up the code into sections.